# what does appreciative mean here?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

Their gift to us was very thoughtful and much **appreciative**.

I am wondering what could the bold term mean.

Other than that, would you learn me a proper synonym for it?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there more context? Given just that sentence, I would have chosen a different word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct word there is *appreciated.* It means *I/we/he/she/they appreciate it (or appreciated receiving it).*